# Send complex sets of data to php from javascript without ajax

Tags: php, javascript, scope

How can javascript pass data, for example from an HTML table, without using AJAX?

**I am lacking the understanding of how to actually pull data, format (into json likely), and pass it.**

I am trying to pass data to a php function that sends a file to the user to download. (something ajax can't handle as I understand it)

**EDIT** - please give an example of posting of some rather complex data.

**EDIT2** - an exmample...

I populate a table via an ajax response Object.  What would be a good way to get this data I am formatting into a form that I can send to a php file via a form?

```
function getSalesByDeviceComplete(responseObj)
{
  var cashTotal = parseInt(responseObj.data[0].cash_total).toFixed(2);
  var creditTotal = parseInt(responseObj.data[0].credit_total).toFixed(2);
  var grandTotal = (parseInt(responseObj.data[0].cash_total) + parseInt(responseObj.data[0].credit_total)).toFixed(2);
  htmlStr += '<ul>';
    htmlStr += '    <li>';
    htmlStr += '        <table class="ui-widget ui-widget-content contentTable">';
    htmlStr += '            <thead>';
    htmlStr += '                <tr class="ui-helper-reset ui-widget-header">'; 
    htmlStr += '                    <th class="contentTableKey">Payment Device</th>';
    htmlStr += '                    <th class="contentTableValue">Sales</th>';
    htmlStr += '                </tr>';
    htmlStr += '            </thead>';
    htmlStr += '            <tbody>';

        htmlStr += '            <tr>';  
        htmlStr += '                <td class="contentTableKey">Credit Card</td>';
        htmlStr += '                <td class="contentTableValue">$'+creditTotal+'</td>';
        htmlStr += '            </tr>'; 
        htmlStr += '            <tr>';  
        htmlStr += '                <td class="contentTableKey">Cash</td>';
        htmlStr += '                <td class="contentTableValue">$'+cashTotal+'</td>';
        htmlStr += '            </tr>';

    htmlStr += '            </tbody>';
    htmlStr += '            <tfoot>';
    htmlStr += '                <tr>';
    htmlStr += '                    <td></td>';
    htmlStr += '                    <td id="salesTotal" class="contentTableValue">$'+grandTotal+'</td>';
    htmlStr += '                </tr>';
    htmlStr += '            </tfoot>';
    htmlStr += '        </table>';
    htmlStr += '    </li>';
    htmlStr += '</ul>';

    $("#contentData").html(htmlStr);
}
```

The response object looks something like...

```
<response_GetSalesByDevice> 
  <data> 
    <cash_total>0.00</cash_total> 
    <credit_total>0.00</credit_total> 
  </data> 
  <success>1</success> 
</response_GetSalesByDevice>
```

Alas, there are several response objects that are *much* more complex than this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use AJAX but with json instead of XML?

Comment: I believe people are trying to figure out why you don't want to use Ajax. If you don't want to reload the entire page by using a post, then you need to request the data asyncrously with Ajax. They are your only 2 options

Comment: I *can't* use ajax because I will be sending an xls file that is generated by said receiving php file

Comment: @Elizabeth - not necessarily, you can post to an iFrame within the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way it "used" to be done (which is of course still very current):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 4):

By posting form data to a PHP script via the browser, rather than using an asynchronous HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

If by "Without AJAX" you mean without using XMLHttpRequest, then the most common way is to fill a hidden field in a form.

Javascript can change a hidden field, then when the user submits the form as usual, the hidden value is passed through as well.

This can be used for things like gathering stats on screen size etc, which are non-critical and can be passed through when Javascript is enabled, or not when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some crossed understanding of what AJAX and JSON are/do or most likely I do not understand what you mean from your question.
If you do not want to use ajax you will have to use the normal submit just like the two people above me suggested.

However, if you are sending a relatively small amount of data you might be able to send a GET request to your PHP script with ajax, which will then respond with a file. Something like:

```
http://yourserver.com/test.php?getVariable=29472938472
```

Test.php script looks at the get variable and returns the associated file.
Entirely possible with AJAX.

Please tell me if I've gone down the wrong path.

Comment: definitely going to be sending complex sets of data.

Comment: By complex you mean bigger than 256 characters ? if you are then you may be able to use post with pretty much same results. Can you post some example data that you are having problems with?

Comment: By complex i mean in size, not in diversity of content, I hope that you will base64encode everything that you are sending (even gzcompress for a good measure)

Comment: What i meant is that the data complexity does not matter as long as you encapsulate it properly. You should either send base64 encoded data instead of plain text, or compress it somehow if you are sending binary. (The base64 only applies really if you are using GET). Does this make my answer abit more clear ?

Answer (score 0):

You could post via a form in the usual way.
The form, however, is targeted at a hidden iframe. This way you stay on the current page and the file that the server returns is handled in the usual browser way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the data directly, you should call a php file that contains:

/myphpfilethatgetsstuff.php
    http://mydatadomain.com/?q=getmesomexmlplease";
    $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
    $json_output = json_decode($json);

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json_output);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Then iterate over the data creating both the file and the html output.

In the main file use this javascript:

```
$('div#results').load("http://mydomain.com/myphpfilethatgetsstuff.php");
```

with this div somewhere:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

and this link:

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/mynewfilewithsessionid.xml">Your File</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to XMLHttpRequest objects is making asynchronous calls via an iFrame imbedded in the page. This is a documented "AJAX" design pattern when xmlhttprequests cannot be used.
There are some components for jquery (ie, AJAX Upload) that utilize this method.

Documentation and sample here:

http://ajaxpatterns.org/IFrame_Call